# getting exception Your FFProbe version is too old and does not support `-help` option

Tags: php, laravel, ffmpeg

I installed **ffmpeg** by doing `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`

From a terminal, when I run `/usr/bin/ffprobe -help` it runs properly, but it is not running from my package.  Instead I get the exception in the title: `Your FFProbe version is too old and soes not support '-help'`

I am using `laravel` and i have installed this package https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: just run "whereis ffmpeg" command

Comment: it is running properly from the terminal but my app is not able to detect

Comment: @SameerShaikh did you get done?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to this issue after 22 days

**Step 1**

Download ffmpeg [link](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html)

**Step 2**

Extract and rename ffmpeg

**Step 3**

**Ubuntu**

```
  $ffmpeg = \FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create(array(
                'ffmpeg.binaries' => /home/shubhamazad/Downloads/ffmpeg/ffmpeg',
                'ffprobe.binaries' =>/home/shubhamazad/Downloads/ffmpeg/ffprobe'
                
  ));
```

**Windows**

```
$ffmpeg = \FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create(array(
          'ffmpeg.binaries' =>'C:\user\Downloads\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe',
          'ffprobe.binaries' =>'C:\user\Downloads\ffmpeg\bin\ffprobe.exe'
                    
      ));
```

Comment: What do you mean by "rename ffmpeg". I've tried this and it doesn't work... running on Windows. :(

Comment: When you downloaded and extract the zip it's a folder named  'ffmpeg-20181119-e3a9630-win64-static' please rename it by ffmpeg.And give the exact path like 'your download directory path \ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe'

Comment: I managed to fix my issue, one more complex thing within IIS.I had to change IIS Application Pool > Advanced Settings > Process Model > Identity from `ApplicationPoolIdentity` to `LocalSystem`.

Comment: The link is down.

Comment: @Rox sorry for the late answer. Did your problem get resolved?

Comment: Nope, where is the link?

Comment: @Rox https://ffmpeg.org/download.html. Please see this link.